# Which is the best language for developing NAPAPI plugins for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome-extension

What is the best language for developing NPAPI plugins for Chrome. I have F# and C# in my PC. Please suggest me a good language which will speed up my development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPAPI is a C API; you can use any language that is compatible with C.

Which is best for you is purely an opinion question, so not really appropriate for SO. I can say that if you are planning on looking at example NPAPI code, it's going to be almost entirely in C++, so that may factor into your decision.